# Counting integers in an array; How to eliminate duplicate output strings

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, integer, counting

I am writing a program that outputs how many times each integer is found in an array of integers. I have accomplished this, however, i have duplicate output strings.

This is the output:

```
>run:
>Please enter integers from 0 to 100: 
1
2
3
4
4
5
0
// 1 occurs 1 time //
2 occurs 1 time //
3 occurs 1 time //
4 occurs 2 times //
4 occurs 2 times //
5 occurs 1 time //
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 14 seconds)
```

So as you can see, "4 occurs 2 times" prints twice since it is found twice in the array.

I just need some direction on how to eliminate the duplicates. Anything would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class WorkSpace3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int key = 0;

        System.out.print("Please enter integers from 0 to 100: ");
        int[] myList = new int[100];
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) 
        {
            myList[i] = s.nextInt();
            if (myList[i] == 0)
                break;
        }

        while (key < myList.length && myList[key] != 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) 
            {

                {   if (myList[i] == myList[key]) 
                    {  count++; }   }
            }


            if (count == 1)
                System.out.println(myList[key] + " occurs " + count + " time ");
            if (count > 1)
                System.out.println(myList[key] + " occurs " + count + " times ");
            key++;
            count = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about `Map` yet? If so, build a `Map<Integer, Integer>` where the key is your number and the value is the count of that number.

Comment: @Andreas I haven't learned Map yet unfortunately, but I am working on trying to figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach that is available to you is to mark the elements that you have counted with zeros. This approach is not universal; it is valid only because you use zero to mark the end of the input sequence by end-user.

You would have to slightly modify your code to use this approach: rather than looking for zero in the `while` loop, set up a variable to mark the length of the sequence. Set it to `myList.length` at the beginning, and then reset to `i` at the break. Now you can walk the list up to this max count, do the counting, and then set zeros into elements that you have already counted.

Answer (score 0):

See the set element:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Making a set element from array You remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

try this using `Map`

```
Map<Integer,Integer> counts=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
 if(counts.contains(myList[i]){
counts.put(myList[i],++counts.get(myList[i]);
 }else{
 counts.put(myList[i],1);
}
```